# ssh-keygen generate keys with sshfp

Tags: git, ssh

I want generate public keys for github  use ssh-keygen。
but when i run

```
ssh-keygen -r rsa -C "mymail@gmail.com"
```

which gives me the results :

```
rsa IN SSHFP 1 1 09ccd47be801ef68972072edcd9701244xxxxxxx   

rsa IN SSHFP 2 1 427b9ec46f0d00eb12b7335d54966d857xxxxxxx
```

and I can't find any files in ~/.ssh . Actually， the directory .ssh don't exists in /home

my vps system is ubuntu 12.04.5

How can I generate ssh kesy for git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSHFP is not something you want, or need, for this. It's used for publishing server fingerprints in DNS.

Run `ssh-keygen` without any arguments to create a new SSH key.